# How to add Intranet style header (string returned from web handler) on every page in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

In a .NET Core Web Application I am using middleware (app.UseMyMiddleware) to add an Intranet Header to the response. The restriction is that the Handler which is formatting the response (MyResponseHandler.FormatResponse) can not be changed as it is used on legacy apps and returns a string value. I have got it working as such but want to limit the processing to Page requests only, rather than every single request that goes through (i.e css/js/images etc).

The FormatResponse basically just takes in the current response as a string, finds the "body" tag and appends a load of html which creates a nice menu bar to be able to access all the other applications.

Firstly, is this a good way to implement a common header in .NET Core?
Everything I've found so far just says to use the Layout page which is fine for a single application, but not for a larger number of applications written in different frameworks.

Secondly, how do I go about filtering ONLY page requests?
I can filter all pages that don't contain '.' but what happens if there's a '.' in a query string for example? I'm also not sure if MVC or razor pages ever have a '.' in the url (not from what I've seen so far).

Thirdly, is there a more efficient way to do this? Going through all this code for every single request seems like it may slow things down a little. Can I filter earlier on to save code execution or is there an alternative way?

Startup.cs

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(MiddlewareExtensions.GenericExceptionHandler);
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMyMiddleware();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

MiddlewareExtensions.cs

```
        public static void UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<LoadIntranetHeader>();
        }
```

LoadIntranetHeader.cs

```
    public class LoadIntranetHeader
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public LoadIntranetHeader(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
            var config = (IConfiguration)context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));

            using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;

                await _next(context);

                context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;

                responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                string response = new StreamReader(responseBody).ReadToEnd();

                if (!context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(".") 
                    && !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/api/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                       response = MyResponseHandler.FormatResponse(config, response);
                }
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd strongly discourage doing this. A minor change on the intranet code could destroy the menu styling completely. Why not just change the views to include a menu?

Comment: I share your concerns but this header is used for all the legacy applications as well so the styling needs to be consistent across web apps without the need to maintain multiple code bases.